# VS2022 Q# Templates and Intellisense

Tags: visual-studio

How do you get Q# Templates and Intellisense in VS2022.
e.g.
VS2019 Q# Application project created using the Q# Application Template.

Open project in VS2022.
Program.qs appears as a text file without intellisense and color formatting.
It builds, runs OK and breakpoints can be set.

Try to create a new Q# Application project in VS2022 and there are no Q# templates.

I de-installed QDK and re-installed it. The re-installation process only sees and modifies VS2019.

Answer (score 0):

A Pre-Release version of the QDK for VS2022 is now available.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=quantum.DevKit64